# Write a record from DB to varchar variable/update trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have two problems and ask for help :)

i have to create triggers on sys tables to log any changes eg. updates, deletes and inserts.

i would like to save logs in table which will have one column to store data from record (old or new - insert/delete) or to store differences between old and new version of a record (update).

My problem is how to store this information, especially how to "convert" simple record into string, and how to log updates. i thought i can use something like:

```
exec ('select ' + @col + ' from deleted')
```

in body of tigger but it does not work.

@col variable is a name of a column. i don't know a names of a columns and its count (i wish that my triggers should be universal for every table). to store column names i use cursor based on command:

```
select 
  COLUMN_NAME 
from 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where 
  TABLE_NAME = (SELECT object_name(parent_obj) 
                FROM sysobjects WHERE id = @@procid)
```

please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Although you can get set up a very [sophisticated auditing mechanism in SQL server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) - you might find this article useful - [it shows simple scripts for basic auditing](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/27/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database.aspx).

Comment: i know that there are some audit tools but i have to do this only with t-sql. i think it could be very usefull. thank you

Comment: The script on the link shows how to set up the table and add triggers to the tables you want to audit.